# undefined is not an object (evaluating newText.split)

Tags: javascript, react-native, split

I have an error I can't seem to work out. I am getting undefined is not an object (evaluating newText.split) when this code runs.

```
  <View style={fieldContainerStyle}>
                <TextInput
                    {...inputProps}
                    {...input}
                    onSelectionChange={(event) => this.setState({ cursorPosition: event.nativeEvent.selection, selection: event.nativeEvent.selection })}
                    onSubmitEditing={() => {
                        const { query, cursorPosition } = this.state;
                        let newText = query;
                        const ar = newText.split('');
                        ar.splice(cursorPosition.start, 0, '\n');
                        newText = ar.join('');

                        if (cursorPosition.start === query.length && query.endsWith('\n')) {
                            this.props.input.onChange(newText)
                        } else if (this.state.allowEditing) {
                            this.props.input.onChange(newText)
                            this.setState({
                                selection: {
                                    start: cursorPosition.start + 1,
                                    end: cursorPosition.end + 1
                                },
                                allowEditing: !this.state.allowEditing
                            });
                        }
                    }}
                    multiline={true}
                    numberOfLines={3}
                    underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
                    blurOnSubmit={false}
                    returnKeyType='none'
                    style={combinedInputStyle}
                />
            </View>
```

Can anyone see the issue?

Comment: Please post a [complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: my guess is this.state.query is undefined

Comment: complete example posted

Comment: Try console.dir(this.state);  I suspect query isn't as you think.

Comment: @MarcusSmith, it isn't  complete is it?

Answer (score 0):

Error and its place suggest you trying to do `undefined.split('')` - check your `this.state.query`, seems like it is not set:

```
 onSelectionChange={(event) => this.setState({ cursorPosition: event.nativeEvent.selection, selection: event.nativeEvent.selection })}
```